# How to make my url looks cool with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

regulars question :P

Current URL

```
http://domain.com/index.php
http://domain.com/index.php?page=submit-hosting
http://domain.com/index.php?page=popular-hosting
```

How write my `.htaccess` to make current URL to be like this

1. When user type `http://domain.com/index.php` url will return to `http://domain.com/` only without `index.php`
2. And page with`$_GET['page']` to be `http://domain.com/submit-hosting/`

Let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google I got

to remove `index.php` or `index.html`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index\.(html?|php)(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.(html?|php)$ ./$1 [R=301,L]
```

to make end with slash

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.*[^/])/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ./$1.php [QSA,L]
```

to make /page-name/

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ ./index.php?page=$1  [QSA,L]
```

Any simple or better from this one?